# Why is my Stored Procedue working well when I run EXEC command, but not working in my Database Chain job? (ORACLE)

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, job-scheduling

I make some db program, create the Chain, define the steps and rules.

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_CHAIN (
chain_name            =>  'Manual_Auto_Refresh',
rule_set_name         =>  NULL,
evaluation_interval   =>  NULL,
comments              =>  NULL);
END;

BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step1', 'PROGRAM_IC_LOCATIONHEADER_0');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step2', 'PROGRAM_IC_R_CODEDATE_0');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step3', 'PROGRAM_IC_R_DNOPEPORT_0');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step4', 'PROGRAM_IC_R_HEALTHCHECKMAX_0');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step5', 'PROGRAM_IC_R_HEALTHCHECKSPL_0');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step6', 'PROGRAM_IC_R_MISSPULLZONE_0');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step7', 'PROGRAM_IC_R_NEWSKUS_0');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step8', 'PROGRAM_IC_R_NUTSANDBOLTS_0');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step9', 'PROGRAM_IC_R_ONLYLISTEDITEMS_0');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step10', 'PROGRAM_IC_R_VALIILNWEIGHT_0');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step11', 'PROGRAM_IC_CLOSE_TASK');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step12', 'PROGRAM_IC_CREATE_TASK_0');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_STEP('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step13', 'PROGRAM_IC_REGRESH_TOGGLE');
END;


BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'TRUE', 'START step1, step2, step3, step4, step5, step6, step7, step8, step9, step10');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE ('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step1 COMPLETED AND step2 COMPLETED AND step3 COMPLETED AND step4 COMPLETED AND step5 COMPLETED AND step6 COMPLETED AND step7 COMPLETED AND step8 COMPLETED AND step9 COMPLETED AND step10 COMPLETED', 'START step11');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE ('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step11 COMPLETED', 'START step12');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE ('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step12 COMPLETED', 'START step13');
DBMS_SCHEDULER.DEFINE_CHAIN_RULE ('Manual_Auto_Refresh', 'step13 COMPLETED', 'END');
END;
```

The Step 11 will start after step1 - step10 finished, and each program is a Stored Procedure.

For now, my chain will always hanging on **Step12** and it never finished or throw any error...

I try to run stored procedure for Step 12 using EXEC command and it is running perfertly.

**STEP12** is the stored procedure doing the insert data into one table.

and here is the code for stored proceudre Step 12:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE IC_CREATE_TASKS_P AS 
     startnumber number(10,0);
     maxCount number(10,0);
     taskName varchar(254);

    BEGIN

        SELECT count(*) INTO maxCount from ICRTASKREFERENCE;
        startnumber:=1;
         WHILE startnumber <= maxCount
            LOOP      

                SELECT TASKCODE INTO taskName from ICRTASKREFERENCE WHERE TASKREFERENCEID = startnumber;
                taskName := UPPER(taskName);
                BEGIN
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO ICTASK (
                        STATUS,
                        ISDELETED,
                        DC,
                       SOURCETABLEID,
                        CATEGORY,
                        TASKCODE,
                        TASKTYPE,
                        SOURCETABLECODE,
                        MODIFIEDON,
                        MODIFIEDBY,
                        CREATEDON,
                        PRIORITY,
                        WAC,
                        LOCNID
                    ) 
                    SELECT 
                        ''OPEN'',
                        ''0'',
                        newFlag.WHSE,
                      newFlag.MSTID,
                        taskReferenceTable.CATEGORY,
                        taskReferenceTable.TASKCODE,
                        taskReferenceTable.TASKTYPE,
                        taskReferenceTable.SOURCETABLECODE,
                        SYSDATE,
                        ''Administrator'',
                        SYSDATE,
                        taskReferenceTable.PRIORITY,
                        newFlag.WAC,
                        newFlag.LOCNID                
                     FROM 
                    (SELECT * from '||taskName||' WHERE NEWFLAG = 1)  newFlag cross join (SELECT * from ICRTASKREFERENCE WHERE TASKREFERENCEID =  '||startnumber||'   ) taskReferenceTable  WHERE MSTID NOT IN (SELECT SOURCETABLEID FROM ICTASK)';
                --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( ''||taskName||' '  );
                END;
                            startnumber := startnumber +1 ;
            END LOOP;

    END;
```

**The point is EXEC command running the Stored Procedure in SQL developer perfertly, and I get all the data I need. Why it is not working after I put this into a Chain job?**

Comment: assuming you found and read your scheduler job task logs?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Yes, the Step 12 just hangging there running and running. There are no error show up. After I force drop the Job it said ''Step 12 has been forced cancell by user''.

Comment: run it again - when it hangs, check the wait events for your session. Any blocking locks? if you can, use real time sql monitoring to see how long your SQL is taking. How many rows is that inserting? could be contention or just it's taking longer than you think it does

Comment: also, whenever i see 'cross join' my bad-code-radar starts to bleep...

Comment: Never used chains before but from a read of the doco at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse009.htm#ADMIN12459 it is possible your chain has stalled. You are testing for completed, if this procedure where to error for any reason the step would be marked as FAILED and as you have no check for that would cause the chain to stall......  Maybe add some exception handling and see if you are getting an error.